# Converting C++ string/wchar_t* to C# string?

Tags: c#, c++, string, com, com-interop

Question: I need to call a C# dll from a C++ executable.
I use COM, and it works fine for int, long and bool. But I can't get a string along...

The IDL file says it's a BSTR, but I can't pass it correctly, and neither retrieve one.
I tried using wchar_t* and using sysalloc as I did with VB6, but that doesn't seem to work.

Anybody knows how, or what might be wrong ?

Comment: Using `SysAllocString` to go from a `wchar_t*` to a `BSTR` is certainly the correct route.  Can you give more details on what goes wrong when you do this?  Compilation errror, runtime exception, etc ...

Comment: I get nothing in C# and I only get questionmarks back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ATL you can do this:

```
std::string theString = "hello";
CComBSTR bstr(theString.c_str());
DoSomething(bstr);  // Function that takes a BSTR as an argument
```

Or if no ATL:

```
const wchar_t* theString = L"hello";
BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(theString);
DoSomething(bstr);
SysFreeString(bstr);
```