# How to treat COM references with methods that use ref sbyte in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, atl

I have the following IDL definition for a method in my native ATL COM project:

```
[id(1)] HRESULT Create([in] CHAR* a, [out] Details* b);
```

I have added a reference to my COM object from my C# project and it has generated the stub for this function for me, which I need to call:

```
void Create(ref sbyte a, out SampleNativeLib.Details b)
```

I would have expected the library to let me use a string as the `ref sbyte a` parameter on this function.

How can I call the `Create` method it has generated? Are there any alternatives to have it accept the `ref sbyte a` parameter as a string instead?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2561927/1132334) might get you started (same in other direction)

Comment: @dlatikay I'm trying to go from managed to native here, not the other way around...

Comment: what I'm trying to say is it would work just the same the other way round: rewrite the ATL function so it would accept a BSTR, that will map to `string` in c#. [another related one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13474480/1132334)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the [string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367270(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute. This ensures that the `CHAR` pointer is treated as a string:

```
[id(1)] HRESULT Create([in, string] CHAR* a, [out] Details* b);
```